nestjs-i18n: i18n is undefined in custom pipes in nestjs
I have a nestjs project and I have implemented localization using nestjs-i18n. It is working on the controller and service.
It's also working on the DTO level, but I am facing issues with custom pipes.
In the custom pipe, it is undefined. I correctly configured nestjs-i18n in the project.
Here are my codes:
// Custom Pipe:
import { PipeTransform, Injectable, ArgumentMetadata } from '@nestjs/common'
import { I18nContext, I18nService } from 'nestjs-i18n';
import {  GetRequestQueryDto } from '../dto/request.dto'

    @Injectable()
    export class ValidationPipe implements PipeTransform {
      private readonly i18n: I18nService
    
      transform(value: any, metadata: ArgumentMetadata): GetRequestQueryDto {
        switch (metadata.type) {
          case 'QUERY':
            const message = this.i18n.t('lang.HELLO',{ lang:   I18nContext.current()?.lang }) // This is not working
            return message;
    
          default:
            return value
        }
      }
    }

// Controller:
import { I18n, I18nContext, I18nValidationExceptionFilter } from 'nestjs-i18n'

    @Get('test')
    @UseFilters(new I18nValidationExceptionFilter())
    @UsePipes(new ValidationPipe())
    async test(
      @I18n() i18n: any,
      @CustomHeaders() headers: HeaderDto,
      @Query() query: TestDTO
    ): Promise<any> {
        const message = await i18n.t('lang.PRODUCT.NEW',{args: { name: 'Toon' }})
        return message;
    }

// main.ts:
app.useGlobalPipes(new I18nValidationPipe());
app.useGlobalFilters(new I18nValidationExceptionFilter());

// app.module.ts:
I18nModule.forRootAsync({
      useFactory: (configSrv: NestConfig) => ({
        fallbackLanguage: "en",
        loaderOptions: {
          path: path.join(__dirname, '../i18n/'),
          watch: true,
        },
      }),
      resolvers: [
        { use: QueryResolver, options: ['lang'] },
        new HeaderResolver(['x-lang']),
        AcceptLanguageResolver,
      ],
      inject: [NestConfig],
    })


I tried constructor(@Optional() private readonly i18n?: I18nService) {} in ValidationPipe pipe but its not working
